# NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsbundle

I am trying to write a simple IO wrapper for Swift.

To test this I have a file named "Test.txt" in my project root.

I have added this file to Build Phases within Build Bundle Resources, as suggested by everyone else who has had this problem.

[image: Build Bundle Resources]

I have implemented a very simple File class with one read function with the intent to output the contents of the file.

```
class File2{
    let resourceName: String
    let type: String
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()


    init(resourceName: String, type: String = "txt"){
        self.resourceName = resourceName
        self.type = type
        println(self.bundle)
    }

    func read(){
        let path = self.bundle.pathForResource("Test.txt", ofType: "txt") //Hard coded these in just to make sure Strings contained no whitespace
        println(path) //This returns nil...why?
        var error:NSError?
        //print(String(contentsOfFile:path!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)!)
        //return String(contentsOfFile:path!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)!
    }
}
```

When I print the contents of the bundle I get a URI to a specific location on my filesystem, which I assume is the virtual location of the app in the simulator. Navigating to it reveals that it does indeed contain my "Test.txt" file.

Now all I want to do is get the path to that file.

I do this by calling: `self.bundle.pathForResource("Test.txt", ofType: "txt")`

This returns "nil"

**Why? :)**

Comment: `let path = self.bundle.pathForResource("Test.txt", ofType: "txt")`, means looking for the resource `Text.txt.txt`... one of the `txt` is unnecessary in the parameters.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Do not include the `.txt` in the **name** parameter, pass it as the **extension** parameter.
From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1410989-path):

> **extension**
>   The filename extension of the file to locate.
>   If you specify an empty string or nil, the extension is assumed not to exist and the file is the first file encountered that exactly matches name.

#### Swift3

```
let bundle = Bundle.main
let path = bundle.path(forResource: "Test", ofType: "txt")
```

#### Swift1 & Swift2

```
let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let path = self.bundle.pathForResource("Test", ofType: "txt")
```

#### Objective-C

```m
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString* path = [bundle pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"txt"];
```

Comment: There are no words. Thank you.

Comment: **Swift** `let path = self.bundle.pathForResource("Test", ofType: "txt")`

Comment: You can also leave the type as nil and use the full resource name: `let path = self.bundle.pathForResource("Test.txt", ofType:nil)`

Comment: I found one answer that worked for a very similar problem that I had, also returning nil from Bundle, in my case there was nothing to do with code, it was the way that the file was being imported. Thanks Leo Dabus. Available at: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548771/swift-how-do-i-get-the-file-path-inside-a-folder>.

Answer (score 18):

In swift 3.0, write with

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Test", ofType: "txt")
```

Answer (score 13):

Replace your

```
 let path = self.bundle.pathForResource("Test.txt", ofType: "txt")
```

with

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Test", ofType: "txt")
```

Answer (score 7):

Replace

```
let path = self.bundle.pathForResource("Test.txt", ofType: "txt")
```

with

```
let path = self.bundle.pathForResource("Test", ofType: "txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource returns nil is file is not properly added to the target. When you drag and drop the file in bundle, please make sure that "Add To Target" checkbox and "Copy items if needed" checkbox is selected.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who are trying to access resources in Unit Tests, I faced a problem where the resource was not found in the main bundle and my solution was to search for the path in all bundles, this way I don't have to specify a bundle identifier, where `fileName` is a string passed into the function and of course the type can be anything you'd want.

```
NSString *path;

for (NSBundle *bundle in [NSBundle allBundles]) {
    path = [bundle pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"json"];
    if (path) {
        break;  // Here is your path.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **ofType** parameter appended to the resource name, so replace this line:

```
 let path = self.bundle.pathForResource("Test.txt", ofType: "txt")
```

to something like this:

```
 let path = self.bundle.pathForResource("Test", ofType: "txt")
```

The **Build Bundle Resources** is also necessary to check.

Comment: The resource must be in the top level setting when you want to use it from test cases.