# url(forResource) keeps returning nil for image in the bundle

Tags: swift

I am working on a TV app in XCode with Swift 3. I need to get the URL for an image in the Bundle, however when I use the following function

```
func urlForResource() -> String {
    let image = "oasiscover"
    if let imageURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: image, withExtension: "jpg", subdirectory: "img") {
        return imageURL.absoluteString
    }
    return ""
}
```

it always return an empty string. If I try the function with another file, like a .js file or a .tvml file, the function returns the URL. But with images it doesn't.

I read some solutions that said I should select Select Folder References instead of Create Groups when dragging the image into the project. However this doesn't work.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/34548888/2303865

Comment: I did try dragging the folder and choosing Select Folder References. I got the blue folder. Still, I get nil.

Comment: Nil or empty string? absoluteString it is not the same as path. Btw why don't you return the URL?

Comment: I am getting an empty string because the second return statement (which returns an empty string) is executing since the if let returns nil.

Comment: You should pass name not image `Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "jpg", subdirectory: "img")`

Comment: Whi do you need a string? change the return type to URL

Comment: I edited the function, this is a test so I'm not receiving any arguments.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your files in your project?

Comment: Btw just did that here and it returns the url without a problem

Comment: Check your app target Build phases and make sure the img folder it is listed inside copy bundle resources https://www.dropbox.com/s/kg95of5hqfr4bwz/ImageSource.zip?dl=1

Comment: Also make sure your images do have an extension .jpg

Comment: The Build Phases did it. Not sure why my photos were not being added. Thanks for your help and patience.