# Xcode does not detect custom font

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts, storyboard

I added custom font in xcode, target membership is checked but it does not seen in custom fonts menu.

[target membership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smI75.png)

[location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiuH6.png)

[info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaRXg.png)

[copy bundle resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lF1n.png)

Comment: You should add the fonts to the macOS system as well. The Fonts folder should be blue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548771/swift-how-do-i-get-the-file-path-inside-a-folder/34548888

Comment: Did you try this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all the suggestions but it didn't work. Hardware reset resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

You should add your custom font to `info.plist` too. did you do that ?
you should add a row with `Fonts provided by application` and enter your font names in that array

Comment: yes, i did but it did not work, you can check out the ss

Answer (score 0):

`Project Name > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources.`

You should see all `font_name.ttf` files listed. if you can't see that add your fonts files here. that should solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: i tried but it did not work, and i added ss you can check out

Comment: @OrkunAkkaya not entire folder, try to add all ttf files separately.